# How to slice a panda data frame to get required results

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm working on this problem in Jupyter where I have to get the desired result. The initial DataFrame is:

```
print(df1)
df2=pd.DataFrame({'custID':[1,2,3,4],
                 'cust_age':[20,35,50,85]},columns=['custID','cust_age'])
print(df2)
```

I have managed to get my input and output to get like this.

```
grouped = df2[df2.cust_age.lt(50).groupby(df2.custID).transform('any')]
grouped

custID  cust_age
0   1   20
1   2   35
```

But I'm required to get the answer to come out simply as [1, 2] and I cannot get the last step for slicing figured out because I'm not great at it. Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure I understand the question/problem here. Do you just want `grouped.custID.tolist()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by

```
In[1]: df2[df2.cust_age.lt(50)].custID.values
Out[2]:array([1, 2])
```

or

```
In[1]: df2[df2.cust_age < 50].custID.tolist()
Out[2]:[1, 2]
```

depending on whether you want to get a numpy-array or a list.